# Why Sanji is missing so much in the manga?

Tags: one-piece

An announcement came at the annual One Piece Super Stage Event last December that promised to change all that. The staff and Sir Eiichiro Oda assured fans that Sanji will return in 2016 with an origin story. Sanji's voice actor Hiroaki Hirata will also return. But still nothing for Sanji he is still missing.

Why this will be? Is it possible that he is a weak one amoung straw hats?

Comment: yes that i know, but still nothing revealed his true identity yet....

Comment: that's why i posted this question as i like sanji's character , but as of now he seems so missing so much....

Comment: star.. what? Did you mean straw hat?

Comment: @Darjeeling yes exactly it was a bit typo mistake

Comment: If the mangaka has announced that there will be an origin story, and it still hasn't come out, most likely, the mangaka is paving the plot to create an instance for the story to be told. There's no rush..

Comment: I clearly disagree that Sanjie is a weak one among straw hats.

Comment: i agree with u @bot, he is clearly the number 3 in the crew if u talk about strength and if we talk about tactics, i would even say he is number one!
now, we know his family are all assassins, he will additionally have some more move which make him even stronger if he shows them.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: Sanji is busy with other stuff, but the next big arc is about him.**

It is very simple why Sanji went missing.

Chapter 812:

> Sanji is told, that he has to marry some chick and he has to leave the straw hat pirates.[image: Chapter 812]

Chapter 814:

> The crew gets a letter from Sanji, telling them that he has to meet with that girl.[image: Chapter 814]

Chapter 822:

> The crew starts its journey to save Sanji.[image]